# Create a byte array and get same output both Java and JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, arrays

I have this byte array in Java

```
private static final byte[] somevalue = new byte[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
```

And the result of print this array is (**System.out.println("Byte: "+somevalue)**)

```
Byte: [B@ab95e6
```

The question is, how I can create that byte array and get the same result using JavaScript?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
System.out.printf("Byte: %s\n", Arrays.toString(somevalue));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The result you're seeing is the default output of the toString() method of Java's array class. Javascript doesn't have that, and frankly there's no reason why you'd want that. It's just the type of the array [B (1 dimensional byte array) and its memory location  (although that's not specified in the standard, but in the Oracle implementation that's it).

Comment: Really? emm exists any way to convert that output to I don't know... hex or string ?

Comment: I need to do that because I need to encrypt in AES in JS and decrypt in Java, but the initial variables (iv, key) should be a byte array but the the output of encryption will be different. So, when I convert my string to bytes in JS, display this: [48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,97,98,99,100,101,102];

Comment: Ah, your wording was confusing. I thought you wanted to get the value [B@ab95e6 from a Javascript array. Josh M's solution should work for your need.